# Problem with using cURL in PHP for DeepAI API

Tags: api

So this my code inside the upload.php, before the file gets uploaded to cloudinary (cdn sdk) I want to check for nsfw using DeepAI's Nudity Detection API.

```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mu_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
{
    //array_push($warning, "Uploaded to <a href=\"" . $target_file . "\" target=\"_blank\">here</a>.");
    // CHECK FOR NUDITY!!!!
    // CHECK FOR NUDITY!!!!
    // CHECK FOR NUDITY!!!!
    // CHECK FOR NUDITY!!!!
    // CHECK FOR NUDITY!!!!
    // CHECK FOR NUDITY!!!!
    $ch = curl_init();
    $mu_check_header_array = array('api-key: f26f6d9f-ed5a-4953-8ba5-dc64000246eb', 'file: '.$target_file);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.deepai.org/api/nsfw-detector");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $mu_check_header_array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    array_push($warning, "THIS IS THE OUTPUT: ". $result);


}
```

Now, it keeps giving this output on my page:
"{"err": "error processing given inputs from request"}"

I have tried a lot, and did some research. It's probably something stupid I forget, can someone  help?

Comment: Did you managed to work? I'm getting the same error continously :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $url = "https://api.deepai.org/api/nsfw-detector";
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   $data_string = array('image' => $target_file);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Api-Key: f26f6d9f-ed5a-4953-8ba5-dc64000246eb'));
   $output   = curl_exec($ch);
   $decoded = json_decode($output, TRUE);
```

Comment: This code snippet helped for the options to set, but still gives me 'error processing given inputs from request'. Did something changed with the way it needs to be requested?